# Binary Search Like Algorithm to Find Change in Value in Sorted Array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, search, binary

I need to write an algorithm that seems to be similar to a binary search, but
with a few exceptions.

**Problem:** 
    Given an array of integers, I need to find the index where the value changes.

**Assumption:**
  There is only two possible values in the array, so we only have to worry about 
  it changing values once. (For example, the examples below use `0` and `100`)

**Example(s):**

```
 [0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100] //search would return 4

 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100] //search would return 8

 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100] //search would return 13
```

**Explanation:**

Not a homework problem. I have a problem where I have to calculate an array of sorted
  dates that correspond to a change in price for an item over 2 week span. If the price
  at the end of those dates is different, I want to efficiently find the exact day that
  the price changed.

The method simply needs to be in the format

```
public int FindChangeIndex(int[] input){
    int changeIndex = -1

    //use efficient binary-search 
    //like algorithm to find change index

    return changeIndex;        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a variation of binary search, let consider an array which contains only A and B ( A != B)

`input = A, A, ...B,.. B`

So, our task is to find the first occurrence of `B` in the input.

Assuming that the mid of the input is equal to B, so, the first occurrence of B should be in the first half, and vice versa. We can do this search recursively until the size of the search space is empty.

Assume that the length of the input is `n`. We have our pseudocode:

```
int result = n - 1;
int start = 0;
int end = n - 1;
while(start <= end){
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    if(input[mid] == B){
        result = mid;
        end = mid - 1;
    }else{
        start = mid + 1;
    }   
}
return result;
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to not make the assumption `A < B`?

Comment: @TheJediCowboy actually, `A < B` or `A > B` has no effect to this algo, as you can see, it just uses equal comparison. As long as the input is divided into two separated part, this will work correctly.

Comment: In Binary search A < B is always true

Comment: @PhamTrung what is the significance of `result = min(result,mid)` versus just `result = mid`?